# ClaimsAuthorizationManager.CheckAccess: Handling false without going to login page

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, claims-based-identity

I'm developing an ASP.NET MVC application that's using ACS for authentication. Users must be authenticated to access any part of the site.

I've created and configured my ClaimsAuthorizationManager, put my custom logic in CheckAccess method and I'm using it declaratively on controller methods using ThinkTecture’s IdentityModel attributes.

For instance: [ClaimsAuthorize("Edit", "Clients")]

If an authenticated user attempts to access a resource that they have insufficient privileges to access the CheckAccess method returns false as expected. However, the user is then immediately redirected to the login page again. This is obviously incorrect as the user is already authenticated (just not authorized). What I’d like to happen is for the user to be redirected to a view that informs the user that they don’t have access to the desired resource. I have been unable to find the correct place in the pipeline or configuration to achieve this.

The only way I’ve been able to do it is to throw a custom exception within CheckAccess instead of returning false and then handle the exception in Application_Error. This is obviously incorrect. What is the correct pattern for achieving my desired result?

Thanks

Mat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either handle the 401 in the ASP.NET pipeline or derive from ClaimsAuthorizeAttribute and override the SendUnauthorizedResponse (or similar) method.

Comment: Worked a treat. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

For anyone who's interest, I implemented the suggested solution as follows:

```
    public class CustomClaimAuthorizeAttribute : ClaimsAuthorizeAttribute
{
    public CustomClaimAuthorizeAttribute()
    {
    }

    public CustomClaimAuthorizeAttribute(string action, params string[] resources)
        : base(action, resources)
    {
    }

    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            // User is authenticated but doesn't have sufficent permissions. Redirect to InsufficientPermissions page
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
                new RouteValueDictionary
                {
                    {"Controller", "Security"},
                    {"Action", "InsufficientPermissions"}
                });
        }
        else
        {
            base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);
        }
    }
}
```